# Php Post Restriction using Time and Date?

Tags: php

What is the best way to restrict someone posting a message every 10 minutes using the Time and Date php functions ? I want it to check whether someone has posted something in the last 10 minutes, if so output an error saying they are not allowed to post.

Any information and code examples would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't great if you're going to be using a CDN but it's fast and easy. After someone posts a message drop a timestamp in your session and then check on that the next time they post.

```
if ($_SESSION['post_time'] && $_SESSION['post_time'] <= strtotime('now -10 minutes')) {
  // error
} 
$_SESSION['post_time'] = time();
```

This is open to tampering so it's not perfect by any means. Also, giving a session cookie to anyone that posts is bad for your CDN if you're using one since they usually cannot cache a page for a user that has a cookie. But since you don't really have another way to tracking the user over a 10 minute period it seems to be one of the better options.

Comment: shouldn't it be 'now - 10 minutes' ?

Comment: What about this, <?php
    $found = 0;
    $TodaysDate = date("m/d/y");
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM $data_table2 WHERE DateAdded='$TodaysDate'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($row > 0) {
        $time = date("H:i:s");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            if($row['TimeAdded'] - date("H:i:s") < 10) {
                $found = 1;
            }
        }
    }
?>

Comment: @Gebbo : I see your sql code there and I posted something more intuitive as an answer than what you put.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply ask database if the user posting has already posted "ten minutes before". [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) you will find enough to reach your goal. Another golden link is:

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet86.htm

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Unix datestamp your database posts using time(). This returns a datestamp to you.

Then you compare current time to the time you had inserted in your database from the user like this:

Assume their user id # is 22:

```
// returns datestamp equal to ten minutes before the current time
$threshold = time() - 600;

// see if there are any posts by the user
$sql = 'select from post_table where posted_date > '.$threshold.' and uid=22';
```

Push the $sql string to your query function and if any results happen they already posted within ten minutes ago so you issue an error and bypass the add-record.

Comment: this assumes a uid which is maybe a safe assumption but for anonymous posters there won't be a uid

Comment: @Chuck Vose if you're accepting anon posts, then you need to use $_SESSION and give them temporary UIDs. But you will also want to look at IP addresses as methods to track them. You'll probably also want to write a cookie to their computer. But I don't recommend accepting anon posts. Some users will come from the same IP like on college campuses, so there is a risk of being too strict on IP auth. I wouldn't force IP auth on user accounts against other user accounts.

Comment: @Chuck Vose : the risk with $_SESSION is that a user can close the browser and open it up again and then they get a new $_SESSION. IF you want to stop flooding, you can't rely on $_SESSION or $_COOKIE alone.

Comment: Agreed, it's hard to say what's really the best way; It's a hard problem. I accept that session cookies have some risk, but I wanted to answer the question as fully as I could while acknowledging that sessions are not a silver bullet for allowing anon posts.